# Error message 'procedure has no parameters'

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, parameters, dynamic-sql

When I execute the store procedure, it throws to me this error:

> Msg 8146, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>
> Procedure  has no parameters and arguments were supplied.

I'm thinking because I had some problems with the DATETIME format and had to concat or convert them. After that, I got the error above.

Anyone know whats wrong with the code?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ACC_ARAP_DOC_LIST]
    @DATE_FROM DATETIME,
    @DATE_TO DATETIME,
    @DOC_TYPE_GROUP CHAR(20)='DIV',
    @FILTER_CONDITION NVARCHAR(4000)='',
    @RESULT_MODE NVARCHAR(30)= NULL --'DOC_SUM'
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000) --Select
    DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @WHERE NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @PARAMETER NVARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @GROUP_BY NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @GROUP_ORDER_BY NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @ORDER_BY NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @SQL_SUM_START NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @SQL_SUM_END NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT j1.journal_no, j1.acc_date, j1.partner_code, j1.term_code, j1.due_date, j1.ref_no1, j1.ref_no2,
                                j1.description,j1.sales_person,j1.pay_remark ,j1.amount,j1.acc_amount,j1.currency, j1.match_acc_amount, p1.name as partner_name
                                FROM acc_journal j1 
                                INNER JOIN acc_journal_groupcfg g1 ON g1.group_type=''LST'' AND g1.doc_type_group='''+ @DOC_TYPE_GROUP +''' AND g1.doc_type=j1.doc_type
                                 LEFT OUTER JOIN partner p1 ON j1.partner_code=p1.partner_code 
                                 LEFT OUTER JOIN partner_acc p2 ON p1.partner_id=p2.partner_id) as sql1'
    SET @WHERE = ' WHERE acc_date>=' + convert(varchar(10), @DATE_FROM, 120) +' AND acc_date<=' +convert(varchar(10), @DATE_TO, 120) + ' ' +
       (CASE WHEN ISNULL(@filter_condition,'')<>'' 
                    THEN 'AND '+@filter_condition ELSE '' END)
    SET @ORDER_BY = ' ORDER BY journal_no'

    SET @PARAMETER = '@DATE_FROM DATETIME,@DATE_TO DATETIME,@RESULT_MODE NVARCHAR(30)=''DOC_SUM'',@DOC_TYPE_GROUP CHAR(20)'


    SET @SQL = @SQL + @WHERE + @ORDER_BY

    IF @RESULT_MODE = 'DOC_SUM'
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT j1.journal_no, j1.acc_date, j1.partner_code as Code, j1.term_code, j1.due_date, j1.ref_no1, j1.ref_no2,
                                j1.description,j1.sales_person,j1.pay_remark ,j1.amount,j1.acc_amount,j1.currency, j1.match_acc_amount, p1.name as Name
                                FROM acc_journal j1 
                                INNER JOIN acc_journal_groupcfg g1 ON g1.group_type=''LST'' AND g1.doc_type_group='''+@DOC_TYPE_GROUP +'''AND g1.doc_type=j1.doc_type
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN partner p1 ON j1.partner_code=p1.partner_code 
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN partner_acc p2 ON p1.partner_id=p2.partner_id) as sql1'
        SET @SQL_SUM_START= 'SELECT Code, Name, COUNT(*) as Count, SUM(acc_amount) as Total_Amount FROM ('
        SET @SQL_SUM_END= ') as SQLsum'

        SET @GROUP_BY = ' GROUP BY Code, Name'
        SET @GROUP_ORDER_BY = ' ORDER BY Code, Name'
        SET @SQL2 = @SQL_SUM_START + @SQL +@SQL_SUM_END + @GROUP_BY + @GROUP_ORDER_BY
    END

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT j1.journal_no, j1.acc_date, j1.partner_code, j1.term_code, j1.due_date, j1.ref_no1, j1.ref_no2,
                                j1.description,j1.sales_person,j1.pay_remark ,j1.amount,j1.acc_amount,j1.currency, j1.match_acc_amount, p1.name as partner_name
                                FROM acc_journal j1 
                                INNER JOIN acc_journal_groupcfg g1 ON g1.group_type=''LST'' 
                                 AND g1.doc_type_group='''+@DOC_TYPE_GROUP+'''
                                 AND g1.doc_type=j1.doc_type
                                 LEFT OUTER JOIN partner p1 ON j1.partner_code=p1.partner_code 
                                 LEFT OUTER JOIN partner_acc p2 ON p1.partner_id=p2.partner_id) as sql1'
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @WHERE + @ORDER_BY

    --PRINT @SQL
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @SQL2, @PARAMETER,
    @DOC_TYPE_GROUP=@DOC_TYPE_GROUP,
    @DATE_FROM=@DATE_FROM,
    @DATE_TO=@DATE_TO
END
```

Comment: SQL Server? Please tag product used, since this doesn't look like ANSI SQL.

Comment: Call procedure issue....

Comment: @jarlh I'm Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2014.

Comment: need parentheses in parameter declaration ?

Comment: Nonsensical code after `EXEC sp_executesql `

Comment: @leppie why is it nonsensical? Anyway, you have any solution to the problem?

Comment: If you don't set `@RESULT_MODE` to `DOC_SUM` then `@SQL2` never gets set to anything. You should remove that from the last line.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things wrong with your query. It all boils down to the last [`sp_executesql`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) command.

The actual error occurs because you are not setting `@SQL2` to be anything other than an empty string (unless `@RESULT_MODE` has been given a specific value). This means that `sp_executesql` is being given a blank list of parameters then you still pass in further parameters.

1. You are passing in `@SQL2` as the second parameter. I don't think this is needed. It's not always set to anything and when it is, it's a `SELECT` statement of it's own. The second parameters should be the list of parameters you are passing in.
2. The parameters you pass in don't appear to be used at all. Either use them in the dynamic SQL or remove them completely.

Without knowing about your schema/data it's impossible to be more specific, but it looks like your last line could simply be:

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

Comment: Okay, it appears @SQL2 isn't the problem. Although it is an empty string when not set as 'DOC_SUM', I'm just trying to execute the store procedure. I removed the below code and put the last line like you suggested, yet it still throws the same error.

Comment: If you change the last line to what I wrote, it's impossible that you are getting the same error.

Comment: The error: 'Procedure has no parameters' AND 'Arguments were supplied'. Hows does that relate?

Comment: You haven't used the same code that I have given you. What comes AFTER the execute line?